# Excel Formula with Nested IF/LEFT/AND Functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I created a formula with nested IF statements that is working fine, but I need to add some more logic to it. I would be nesting additional statements in the formula, and I'm getting a bit confused on the proper way to go about it.

Current formula is:

```
=IF(LEFT(G3,1)="1","998",IF(LEFT(G3,1)="2","998",IF(LEFT(G3,1)="3","998",IF(LEFT(G3,1)="4","996",IF(LEFT(G3,1)="5","996",K3)))))
```

This is working fine, but now I need to add the additional logic:

- If G3 begins with "9" and K3 does not begin with "075", "076", or "089" then cell equals "997"

My failed attempt was something like this:

```
IF(LEFT(G3,1)="1","998",IF(LEFT(G3,1)="2","998",IF(LEFT(G3,1)="3","998",IF(LEFT(G3,1)="4","996",IF(LEFT(G3,1)="5","996",IF(LEFT(G3,1)="9"(AND(LEFT(K3,3)<>"075"))K3))))))
```

With this being the attempted nested statement I added:

```
IF(LEFT(G3,1)="9"(AND(LEFT(K3,3)<>"075"))
```

Then obviously I would need to repeat this a few more times for "076" and "089", but I have yet to get it right for just one of these.

I know this could be accomplished through some VBA code, but for this file, I am hoping to avoid the VBA and keep it limited to only formulas.

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:**
Using the answers from Scott & L. Scott, I still have "997" being input into the cell even when the value of K3 is 075, 076, or 089. Below is a screenshot of L. Scott's recommended formula with the result still showing "997".
[image]

Comment: When faced with nested IF()s, you might consider using a SWITCH() instead.

Comment: The formula does not work because the `075` in K3 is not `"075"` but `75` that is formatted to look like `075`  And a formula will see what is in the formula bar and not the formatted version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a formula you could use:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(G3,1)={"1","2","3"}))>0,"998",IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(G3,1)={"4","5"}))>0,"996",IF(AND(SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(G3,1)="9"))>0,SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(K3,3)={"075","076","089"}))=0),"997")))
```

If `K3` is an actaul number and not text than @ScottCraner has a very good point and it won't see the leading zero. To overcome this you should add `'` in front of value in cell `K3`.

Comment: Thank you! It was the leading zero as the issue. I addressed that after I was pointed out on here, and now this formula (and the others mentioned) are working. Its helpful to see a few different formulas to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it in your existing style of nested if:

`=IF(LEFT(G3,1)="1","998",IF(LEFT(G3,1)="2","998",IF(LEFT(G3,1)="3","998",IF(LEFT(G3,1)="4","996",IF(LEFT(G3,1)="5","996",IF(AND(LEFT(G3,1)="9",NOT(OR(OR(LEFT(K3,3)="075",LEFT(K3,3)="076"),LEFT(K3,3)="089"))),"997",K3))))))`

```
=
IF(LEFT(G3,1)="1","998",
  IF(LEFT(G3,1)="2","998",
    IF(LEFT(G3,1)="3","998",
      IF(LEFT(G3,1)="4","996",
        IF(LEFT(G3,1)="5","996",
          IF(
            AND(
              LEFT(G3,1)="9",
              NOT(
                OR(
                  OR(
                    LEFT(K3,3)="075",
                    LEFT(K3,3)="076"),
                  LEFT(K3,3)="089"
                )
              )
            ), "997", K3
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment! I'm testing this out and it is putting the "997" even when K3 is 075. I think I understand the logic of the nested statements you added, but I don't see why it isn't keeping the value from K3 when it is 075, 076, 089?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but it should be that the AND() returns false if K3 is "075" because the NOT() returns false because the OR() returns true because the OR returns true. If that's not the case, build it up from the inside out to see when the logic breaks down.